# How can I deploy a create-react-app website in development mode instead of production

Tags: reactjs, iphone, webpack, deployment

I am working on a landing page for a chrome dev tool that my team and I have created. Our landing page contains a sandbox intended to allow visitors to test our dev tool. Upon deployment, we realized that the dev tool won't work with the sandbox, because the sandbox is deployed in production mode (minified/uglified component names, no access to fiber tree render properties).
I've seen other posts talk about the performance issues that come from deploying in development mode, which I am not concerned about, and that shows me that it is possible.
Our app is using Webpack to build the bundle, and Netlify to deploy. The website itself is built in React/Recoil.

Here's a link to our repo just in case:

https://github.com/open-source-labs/Recoilize

Answer (score 1):

Customizing Environment Variables for Arbitrary Build Environments
You can create an arbitrary build environment by creating a custom .env file and loading it using env-cmd.

For example, to create a build environment for a staging environment:

1. Create a file called .env.staging
2. Set environment variables as you would any other .env file (e.g. REACT_APP_API_URL=http://api-staging.example.com)
3. Install env-cmd

   npm install env-cmd --save

   or

   yarn add env-cmd

Add a new script to your package.json, building with your new environment:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging npm run build"
  }
}
```

Now you can run npm run `build:staging` to build with the staging environment config. You can specify other environments in the same way.

Variables in .env.production will be used as a fallback because NODE_ENV will always be set to production for a build.